# IPSec: Reason for differentiating between Security Associations and Security policies

Tags: ipsec

In IPSec, why does it make sense to differentiate between Security Associations and Security policies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always liked that definition from [tcpipguide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPSecSecurityAssociationsandtheSecurityAssociation.htm)

> **Security Policies:**
>
> A security policy is a rule that is programmed into
> the IPSec implementation that tells it how to process different
> datagrams received by the device. For example, security policies are
> used to decide if a particular packet needs to be processed by IPSec
> or not; those that do not bypass AH and ESP entirely. If security is
> required, the security policy provides general guidelines for how it
> should be provided, and if necessary, links to more specific detail.
>
> Security policies for a device are stored in the device's Security
> Policy Database (SPD).
>
> **Security Associations:**
>
> A Security Association (SA) is a set of
> security information that describes a particular kind of secure
> connection between one device and another. You can consider it a
> "contract", if you will, that specifies the particular security
> mechanisms that are used for secure communications between the two.
>
> A device's security associations are contained in its Security
> Association Database (SAD).

The former says that if you see a packet that looks like it has characteristics X do Y.
The latter says that with this host we talk IPSec in this ways.

Might help if you think of it as stateless and statefull, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

An SA also can (should) have a lifetime such as number of packets, minutes etc.  Before the SA expires, a new SA is created, using a new key negotiated by IKE.

The more cypher text encrypted using the same key increases the chance of a [Ciphertext Only Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext-only_attack)

Also if the key is broken, only a portion of the traffic is compromised.